# Github Page not updating without clearing my browser data

Tags: html, github, github-pages

So I've just got up and running with Github Pages and for some reason every time I update the website it doesn't update without me having to clear my browsing data which is a real pain. I have no clue what is going on as I am new to this and I am learing HTML and CSS so if somebody could help that'd be amazing!

Github Page: `https://bentheminernz.github.io/codingwebsite/`
Github Repo: `https://github.com/Bentheminernz/codingwebsite`

Comment: I'm not sure that's about browser cache. Every time you push some commits, it take some time for Github pages to be built. You can track that under Action on your github repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be facing the question of browser cache.

Try cleaning the cache by following the step from the docs [of Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050), or [of Mozilla Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache), or what other browser of you.

You may find a shortcut for forcing refresh cache like [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1103414) helpful, too.

Comment: Yes that does work for me but its still a hassle having to do that and it'd be annoying for people who will view my website. If it matters I am using Microsoft Edge as I prefer over other browsers. (My opinion don't need to laugh at it please)

Comment: Do you find a solution for invalidating the cache of users who have cached the old versioned in their browser? Of course the correct solution is to set http response headers correctly, but not sure how to invalidate client caches so that they can download the latest version with those http headers set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When I merged branches it created a Jekyll file, then my website wouldn't update. I deleted this Jekyll file and voila, the website updated instantly. I only used HTML and CSS in an Index file.